# Why does my soup object return a blank list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to create a program that takes all "Best Sellers" in an amazon search results page and opens each one in a new tab.

This is the code for it as of right now:

```
import webbrowser, sys, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

amazonSearch = "".join(sys.argv[1:])
amazonResults = "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search- 
alias%3Daps&field-keywords=" + amazonSearch

#getting search links
page = requests.get(amazonResults)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
searchLinks = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal s-access-detail- 
page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal"})

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
webbrowser.open_new_tab(amazonResults)
print(page.status_code)
print(searchLinks)
else:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.amazon.com/")
```

Right now, I can't get a list of all the anchor tags with `class=a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal`. When printing the list, it turns out blank. I've also checked the http status code to see if there was something wrong with the URL but everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same right now, the only class that I do find which even starts the same way within that tag is :

```
"a-link-normal s-ref-text-link"
```

do check the results page once again.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
amazonResults = "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=" +"books"
page = requests.get(amazonResults)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
searchLinks = soup.find_all(class_=re.compile("a-link-normal\s.+?"))
```

You might have a case of nothing being present within the selected class.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error is with an extra space inside your class atribute between `page  s-color`

You should have no problems getting those hyperlinks using this syntax:

```
searchLinks = [s['href'] for s in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal"})]
```

**EDIT**:

You must also change your request headers, otherwise the page will not load the content:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

amazonResults = "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=python"

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
    page = s.get(amazonResults)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    searchLinks = [s['href'] for s in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal"})]
    print(searchLinks)
```

Answer (score -1):

`a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal` class is used to indicate sponsored items. Notice that even if in the source of the site, there is a double space between class names, BeautifulSoup gets rid of it somewhere along the way and you need to remove it in order to target the elements.

Use the code below to target both sponsored and normal items:

```
searchLinks = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "a-link-normal a-text-normal"})
```

or

```
searchLinks = soup.select('a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal')
```

if you like [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). I consider the latter for more readable.

There is one bug in your code, you can fix: `amazonSearch = "".join(sys.argv[1:])`. You need to use `+` delimiter to separate search keywords. Use `"+".join(sys.argv[1:])` instead.

Comment: Downvoted for the correct answer? Appreciated. Whoever did that, can you explain why?